# How to setup a Zyxel router in Bridged mode?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, dhcp, nat

I'm attempting to connect a Zyxel VMG8324-B10A to the Modem/Router supplied by my  ISP and to use it in bridged mode. The wireless functionality of the ISP provided router is rather poor.

All existing WAN interfaces are removed and a new bridged one is created with Mode set to bridge and type to Ethernet.

DHCP is set to disabled and a static IP is set within the range of the IP's handed out by the second router. Setting dhcp mode to relay is not possible without disabling NAT. However, all NAT options under NAT -> ALG are currently disabled yet the Zyxel insists it's enabled.

The routers are connected via their ethernet ports.

Currently no DHCP leases are granted when connecting to the Zyxel router. Connecting with a static IP works but internet network traffic is not forwared.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it without bridge mode because by default the home routers usually forward all traffic from its Wlan to their Ethernet lan ports.

So ok to disable DHCP server on this router, ok to disable WAN ports but I think is simpler than you are doing...

reset the router to defaults, do the basic security setting changing router's password, configure the wifi parameters (SSID, encryption, channel and all the wifi stuff). Then do again the WAN disabling and DHCP server disabling. Put a free fixed ip of your range (out of your other router's DHCP range) and that's all!

Good luck.

Comment: No Cigar :( , I've done as you said:  connected the zyxel router to the internet router via the Zyxel's WAN port and set the Zyxel's ip to static 192.168.8.1 (internet router's range is 192.168.1.x)
no DHCP traffic is getting through. Setting the WAN port to emulate LAN port functionality makes no difference.
I've removed all WAN port configuration entries post resetting the Zyxel router's config.

Comment: I never said you must use WAN port. You must use a LAN port to connect zyxel to another LAN port of your other router. Are you sure with the WAN port emulating LAN is exactly the same? why not to try as normal?

Comment: Ah, I presumed the initial line about WAN ports forwarding traffic seemed to apply, say for DHCP traffic.
Using any other LAN port does not solve the issue. No DHCP packets are getting through